# How to display none or .remove() a tag that has # symbol

Tags: jquery, css

I'm having a heck of a time trying to figure this out , I can not use any pseudo selectors as the tables are built dynamically and the order is always changing , I'm trying to remove a td and th class that the server has a #w as the class .

The HTML is provided by the host , not myself , i'd never put any symbol as part of an ID or Class

I set up a jsfiddle to show - http://jsfiddle.net/0oessevv/1/

here is html

```
<th class="#w" title="Year-To-Date Number Of Waiver Moves">#W</th>
<td class="#w">0</td>
```

ofc tried the obvious

```
td.#w {display:none;}
th.#w {display:none;}
```

if this can't be done with CSS , is jQuery an option or will same issue exist

Comment: To use `#` as part of a `class` or `id` name is brilliant.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? `$("*[class*=#]").hide();` http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/0oessevv/7/

Comment: Try this - CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/0oessevv/4/ similar to MalanciaUK's, using CSS selector td[class="#w"] and th[class="#w"]

Comment: Why use symbols when you could have a more readable class design?

Comment: don't do that.  ever.

Comment: This is a terrible terrible thing to do. Stop.

Comment: Guys, do not antagonize the OP. Explain why you feel this is a bad thing to do, and do not use words like stupid. One can't learn if they aren't respected.

Comment: Its not my HTML , this is from the sever , have no idea what the web designer was thinking using this combination, just wanted a way to remove it

Comment: @MShack ugh, I hate it when you have to work with poorly written code. My condolences son!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just escape the # in the CSS:

```
td.\#w {display:none;}
th.\#w {display:none;}
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adamconway/bcdte7d3/1/)

Edit: If you want to get at them with jQuery(I see the question is tagged jQuery) then you need to double-escape it in the jQuery selector:

```
$('.\\#w')
```

I would still try and avoid # and . in class and id names.

[Fiddle with jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/adamconway/bcdte7d3/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the hex unicode representation:

```
td.\23w {display:none;}
th.\23w {display:none;}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/0oessevv/5/

References:

- [W3C: Using character escapes in markup and CSS](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes)
- [Unicode Character 'NUMBER SIGN'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0023/index.htm)